# SSL Problems in Mac using pip install

Tags: python, macos, ssl, openssl, pip

I am having a problem confirming the ssl certificate:

```
("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'tlsv1 alert protocol version')],)",) - skipping
```

I'm trying to do something very basic and I don't understand why this keeps happening. Would someone please advise how to fix this issue?

```
pip install fake-useragent
```

Comment: `pip install pyopenssl -U` might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to ignore SSL errors using:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org fake-useragent
```